# Unity Custom Animation-Rigging Constraint - Smooth follow with offset not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement my own custom Rigging Constraint.
Currently I have this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging;
using System;
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Mathematics;

[BurstCompile]
public struct MyDampTransformJob : IWeightedAnimationJob
{
    public ReadWriteTransformHandle constrained;
    public ReadOnlyTransformHandle source;
    public FloatProperty jobWeight { get; set; }          

    public void ProcessRootMotion(UnityEngine.Animations.AnimationStream stream)
    {   
    }

    public void ProcessAnimation(UnityEngine.Animations.AnimationStream stream)
    {   
        float w = jobWeight.Get(stream);

        if (w > 0f)
        {
           //TODO smooth follow here   
        }   
    }
}   
    
[Serializable]
public struct MyDampTransformData : IAnimationJobData
{
    public Transform constrainedObject;
    [SyncSceneToStream] public Transform sourceObject;

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return !(constrainedObject == null || sourceObject == null);
    }

    public void SetDefaultValues()
    {
        constrainedObject = null;
        sourceObject = null;
    }
}

public class MyDampTransformBinder : AnimationJobBinder<MyDampTransformJob, MyDampTransformData>
{
    public override MyDampTransformJob Create(Animator animator, ref MyDampTransformData data, Component component)
    {
        return new MyDampTransformJob()
        {
            constrained = ReadWriteTransformHandle.Bind(animator, data.constrainedObject),
            source = ReadOnlyTransformHandle.Bind(animator, data.sourceObject)
        };
    }
    public override void Destroy(MyDampTransformJob job) { }    
}


[DisallowMultipleComponent, AddComponentMenu("MyDampTransform")]
public class MyDampTransform : RigConstraint<MyDampTransformJob, MyDampTransformData, MyDampTransformBinder>
{

}
```

Inside the MyDampTransformJob I can access the positions of my source and constrained objects inside the ProcessAnimation method.
I got a static follow working by assigning the source position to the constriant position, but I would like to keep the original offset and have the constraint follow the source smoothly. Every attemped by me has either the offset not working or the smoothing.

How can I add smooth follow?

```
public void ProcessAnimation(UnityEngine.Animations.AnimationStream stream)   
{    
     float w = jobWeight.Get(stream);

     if (w > 0f)
     {
         Vector3 sourcePosition = source.GetPosition(stream);
         Vector3 constrainedPosition = constrained.GetPosition(stream);
        
         if (!hasInitialized)
         {
             initialOffset = constrainedPosition - sourcePosition;
             hasInitialized = true;
         }

         Vector3 newPos = sourcePosition + initialOffset;
         constrained.SetPosition(stream, newPos);
     }
 }
```

Here is my Unity Hirarchy
[[image: Hirarchy1]

Test and Armature are empty GameObjects. The Cube and Sphere are my Objects. The Test holds an Animator and Rig Builder which references Rig1 with MyConstraint.

When I move my Cube the Sphere follows, but I dont seem to get the smooth follow working.
Thanks in advance for any help